# Updates to test file not seen by typescript/webpack/jest

Tags: typescript, webpack, jestjs

I just recently realised that the first run that webpack does, will ensure that my test typescript files compile. Any changes after that aren't seen. I've tried moving the file, changing its name, etc. I always end up with the same issue.  I assume it is a problem with my tsloader, but the test `/\.tsx?$/` is pretty straightforward.

Here's my directory structure:

```
|~front/
| |~app/
| | |~ItineraryBuilder/
| | | |~__test__/
| | | | `-index.spec.tsx
| | | `-index.tsx
| | |+reducers/
| | |-index.tsx
| | `-setupEnzyme.ts
| `-index.html
|-.gitignore
|-index.js
|-jest.config.js
|-package.json
|-tsconfig.json
|-tslint.json
|-webpack.config.js
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "./front/app/**/*"
    ]
}
```

webpack.config.js "^4.0.0-alpha.3"

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path    = require('path');

const APP_DIR   = path.resolve(__dirname, 'front/app');

const config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'front/assets/js/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    alias: { frontapp: path.resolve(__dirname, 'front/app') },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader'},
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      },

      { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader' },
      { enforce: "pre", test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'tslint-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader',
        query: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

**Edit**

Ok, I'm pretty sure this was a misunderstanding on my part. I don't think that webpack should be building my test files. But I put them in the regular project directory. Maybe it's a bug in webpack. For some reason I thought that webpack also did a run over the files for tests, but this is not supposed to be the case. Jest is supposed to build out the files with babel-jest or ts-jest and then all of the non-js files will be mocked out using `moduleNameMapper`.

That being said, I am not sure why webpack is not seeing updates in the `__test__` directories but I am starting to think that I should just exclude them from the build path.

**Another Edit**

I ended up adding a `paths` [section](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/#paths-mapping) to my tsconfig and now jest runs the tests correctly.

**Relevant tsconfig.js configuration**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
          "frontapp/*": ["front/app/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To confirm, if you deliberately introduce an error into a test file, is the error reported the first time you run webpack?  Does your entry point import your test files?  (If not, webpack may not compile them.)  How are you running jest?

Comment: If I introduce an error, I see the error on the first compile, but all further changes to the test file will not be recognized. The error is actually happening during the webpack build phase. The command I am using is `./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d --watch`.

Comment: Also, my entrypoint shouldn't need to import them, webpack compiles the tests the first time, so it definitely sees them. Jest has its own runner.